# $.post data not being sent or received?

Tags: php, jquery

Whenever I load my external PHP page (loadTextBox.php) my variable $verb_value is never being set (always hits the die line). Does this mean my JQuery $.post is not sending data correctly or my external PHP page is not receiving the data correctly? Any ideas how I can fix this issue? **I understand this is prone to SQL injection, but I will focus on that later by using a whitelist.**

Main index page snippet:

```
function loadDoc() 
{
$(document).on('change', '#verb', function() 
    {
        var val = this.value;
        $.post("loadTextBox.php", {verb_value: val}, function(data) 
        {
            $("#textbox").val(data.first);
            $("#textbox2").val(data.second);
            $("#textbox3").val(data.third);
            $("#textbox4").val(data.fourth);
            $("#textbox5").val(data.fifth);
            $("#textbox6").val(data.sixth);
        }, "json");
    });
}
```

loadTextBox.php snippet:

```
$file_absolute = "---Placeholder for correct file path---";
include_once($file_absolute);
$mysql = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
$verb_value = $_POST["verb_value"];

if(!$verb_value)
  die("The value was not set");
```

Comment: did u get any error from firebug?

Comment: @slier No errors popped up in Firebug.

Comment: In Chrome's inspector there's a way to see what values were actually posted - you may want to see if there's something similar in your browser so you can check what verb_value is being set to. I'm not sure `this.value` is the right reference. Alternatively, you could `console.log(val)` before you make the call.

Comment: Is `loadDoc` actually run when the page loads? Also does the event actually trigger?

Comment: @programm3r it really hard to know what wrong with ur code, did it really triggers ajax request? how about put console.log(val) to see if it has an intended value

Comment: I added in the line console.log(val) before sending it, but nothing was displayed in the Firebug console after execution. It's like it didn't even get to that line. I'm not sure where I would look to figure out if this.value is correct syntax or if there's some other syntax problem. Documentation doesn't seem to be that great.

Comment: Have you tried typing "loadDoc()" in console?

Comment: @Nic You mean in the search bar at the top right of the Firebug window?

Comment: @programm3r http://getfirebug.com/logging

Comment: @Nic I still don't understand where you mean for me to type loadDoc()

Comment: You can enter commands in the console where the `>>>` is - type `loadDoc();` there.

Comment: @Nic I was looking on the wrong screen. I typed in loadDoc(); and it says undefined. It also says undefined for other functions I have, and they work.

Comment: @Nic I think that input box is just for searching through the document. It comes up with undefined unless you type it exactly as it looks in the document.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Changing the word "change" to "click" allows everything to function correctly.